# How to make Audio.js inline with text in moodle quiz

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, moodle, audiojs

So I am using audio.js on my website. I customized audio.min.js that there would be only "PLAY/PAUSE" button visible. I want that button to appear at the left of the text. How can I do that?

Cause right now, text always appears bellow "play/pause" button, in a new line. I want it to be on the same line.

The code on my HTML page looks like this:

```
<audio>
  <source src="https://www.website.com/voice/sample.mp3">
</audio>
<!-- This is the text I want to see on the same line as the audio tag which is in use with audio.js -->
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Sorry, was editing at the same time to update it. Please check question for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite audiojs's css in order to modify, and try to add something like this css:

```
.audiojs {
  float:left;
}
```

There is code: https://jsfiddle.net/qp5xjxb9/1/

I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks!! I also had to add 'display: inline' inside the audio.min.js.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Just did it! :)